# Validating XMLEvent

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, saxparser

When parsing XML an error is generated.

"An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x2) was found in the element content of the document"

This is the relevant code:

```
final XMLEventReader eventReader = createXmlReader(params);

 while (eventReader.hasNext()) {

   final XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent(); // Throws Exception here

            if (event.isStartElement()) {
                final String elementName =  
                event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart();
                depth++;
```

While reading the line

```
final XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
```

this exception is triggered:

> An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x2) was found in the element content of the document

Is it possible to create any validation  for XMLEvent ?

Comment: The issue is the input it is not XML or you have the wrong encoding

Comment: ... Or you've messed up when entering/editing data in a multibyte/variable-length encoding such as UTF8 or UTF16. Or you've created a document which can only be processed as XML 1.1, which permits some characters XML 1.0 didn't, and you need to find tools which will support the newer version of the Recommendation (and make sure the document's header doesn't claim it's 1.0). Or you're trying to parse something that was compressed without decompressing it first. Or....

Comment: How can I do the Validation for final XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent(); before it catches the exception